# PHP - Extract JSON result from API to several PHP variables

Tags: php, json, api

I am struggling with the response of calling an API. When I call it I get this back:

```
{
    "id": 22072,
    "currency": "EUR",
    "bitcoin_uri": "bitcoin:2MvAmq3rXhsc3SDrhv2t5Erd9EsvUi9sptB?amount=0.071131",
    "status":"expired",
    "price":"150.99",
    "btc_amount":"0.07113100",
    "created_at":"2018-01-09T20:58:33+00:00",
    "expire_at":"2018-01-09T21:18:33+00:00",
    "bitcoin_address":"2MvAmq3rXhsc3SDrhv2t5Erd9EsvUi9sptB",
    "order_id":"aaaannnddfdfd",
    "payment_url":"https://sandbox.coingate.com/invoice/39bae8ac-8b76-405a-bb5b-38dd6e6f3f91"
}
```

How can I get the invidual values as values of a PHP variable so i can e.g. do:

```
echo $Currency
echo $ID
```

I struggled with JSON and so on, but not sure how to do this. Hope you can help.

Comment: Show us a bit of code, at least the code that you are trying to use to process this JSON String please

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Use json_decode().

Comment: Did you try `json_decode` on this string? ..  http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 4):

You can get the JSON string to an PHP object with [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$apiObject = json_decode($apiResult);
```

After that you can access the different fields like this: `$apiObject->id`, `$apiObject->currency`.

If you need them as direct variables, you need to extract the JSON as associative array and not as object, which can be done with the second parameter of [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$apiArray = json_decode($apiResult, TRUE);
```

Afterwards you can bind the fields as variables with [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php):

```
extract($apiArray);
echo $id;
echo $currency;
```

Comment: thanks philipp, i've tried it but i also used the one below that worked right away. so i used that one, thanks for your help

Comment: In case its needed `extract()` provides a third parameter to prefix each variable name. Example: `extract($apiArray, EXTR_OVERWRITE, 'json_');` would create the variables `$json_id` and `$json_currency`.

Comment: `extract()` really? Should be ashamed of yourself

Answer (score 0):

I assume this string is in a variable like

```
$data = '{"id":22072,
        "currency":"EUR",
        "bitcoin_uri":"bitcoin:2MvAmq3rXhsc3SDrhv2t5Erd9EsvUi9sptB?amount=0.071131",
        "status":"expired",
        "price":"150.99",
        "btc_amount":"0.07113100",
        "created_at":"2018-01-09T20:58:33+00:00",
        "expire_at":"2018-01-09T21:18:33+00:00",
        "bitcoin_address":"2MvAmq3rXhsc3SDrhv2t5Erd9EsvUi9sptB",
        "order_id":"aaaannnddfdfd",
        "payment_url":"https://sandbox.coingate.com/invoice/39bae8ac-8b76-405a-bb5b-38dd6e6f3f91"
}';
```

So use `json_decode()` to convert this JSON string into a PHP datatype, an object in fact like this

```
$obj = json_decode($data);
```

And then address the properties within the object like this, you dont need to move the values from the object into scalar variables, they are just fine left in the object.

```
echo 'The ID is ' . $obj->id;
echo 'The currency is ' . $obj->currency;
```

And so on for all the values you are interested in.

Comment: Ah thanks. I used philips answers and yours and yours worked perfectly right away. Thanks a lot , this really helped a lot!. Looks simple if you know it but it was a struggle. This is exactly what i needed.

Comment: Glad it helped! The normal way to say thanks is to Accept the answer and maybe even upvote it too